# Are questions regarding software testing tools allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is asking for software recommendations relating to software whose primary purpose is testing other software allowed on this site? If so, what kind of information do I need to include when asking, in terms of software requirements, etc?

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

I suppose the minimum requirements would be the host platform, what you're testing, how you want to test it and so on. In short, whatever you need to tell someone to help them help you.